# Notepad++ loses line-break when re-opening with Notepad

Tags: notepad++, line-breaks, notepad

So I was replacing some text on Notepad++ and everything looked fine. I was creating a list and each item was in a different line. But when I re-opened it with the normal Notepad, all the list was in one sentence together and same sentence. It didn't have the line breaks for each item like I saw with Notepad++. How can this be fixed?

Comment: did your original list use linux line breaks and now you are trying to open with windows notepad?

Comment: can you post a sample of the list?

Comment: Both are different editors. Notepad++ or any other programming editor uses some rich formatting for that. Else normal text won't show up colored. Notepad gives you true output. Understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to convert the line endings to use Carriage Return + Line Feed, which is what Windows (and consequently Notepad) uses to separate lines.

This can be done by selecting `Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows (CR LF)`

Then save your file with the new line endings.

Comment: First show the current line endings so the OP can see the difference...
View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line